# Expand variables in upstart script

Tags: upstart, environment-variables

I have written several upstart scripts to start `transmission-daemon` for several users. The script is this:

```
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0 and runlevel [235])
stop on runlevel [016]

kill timeout 50

respawn

env USER=user
env PIDFILE=/var/run/transmission-user.pid

script
    DAEMON=$(which transmission-daemon) || exit 0
    CONFIGDIR=/home/$USER/.config/transmission-daemon

    exec start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid $USER --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --exec $DAEMON -- -f --config-dir $CONFIGDIR --logfile $CONFIGDIR/daemon.log
end script

post-stop exec rm -f $PIDFILE
```

I would convert this:

```
env USER=user
env PIDFILE=/var/run/transmission-user.pid
```

To this:

```
env USER=user
env PIDFILE=/var/run/transmission-$USER.pid
```

But upstart doesn't allow.
I can do it if I move those lines to the script section:

```
script
    USER=user
    PIDFILE=/var/run/transmission-$USER.pid
    ...
end script
```

But in this case, the PIDFILE, in post-stop section, is empty.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 10):

This is a fairly old bug in upstart:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/upstart/+bug/328366

To get the variable in post-stop and script... you'll just have to set it both times to work around the bug.